# What is the one instance of imala in Qalun al-Nafi'?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation, uloom-al-quran, reading-quran, quran-memorization

The Wikipedia page on [Imala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Im%C4%81la) states:

> Many qirāʾāt of the Quran implement imāla at least once. Some, like those of Hafs or Qalun, use it only once, but others, like those of Hamzah az-Zaiyyat and Al-Kisa'i, use it regularly.

The one instance in [Hafs 'an 'Asim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafs) occurs in Surah Hud, [verse 41](https://quran.com/en/hud/41), but where does the one instance in [Qalun 'an Nafi'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qalun) occur? If it's the same verse, is the Qalun version of the imala recited in the same way as the one in Hafs? I would especially appreciate a link to a qari reciting the verse in Qalun as I've been unable to find one on YouTube.

Comment: The title asks about Warsh and the question content asks about Qalun. I assume the title is a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one time Qaloon does imalah kubra is in Surah Tawbah 109.

It is the verse:

[image]

There is imalah in هَارٍ.

See recitation of the verse on YouTube:

https://youtu.be/3FriDmMMSoo?t=1989

Comment: Perfect, thank you.